# Delete indvidual messages from JBoss 5.1 internal jms (service integration bus)

Tags: jboss, jms, message-queue

I am writing an API to delete messages from Jboss service integration bus.
I need to provide methods for deleting individual messages and also all the messages (purge) in the queue.

I tried finding the list of operations available on a queue using JMX. Below is the code I used for getting the list of operations. It has an operation "removeAllMessages" which would delete all the messages in the queue. However, I did not find any operation that would help me delete individual messages from the queue. Also, I found the QueueBrowser API of JMX. But the specification says that the class does not delete messages from the queue.

```
MBeanServerConnection connection = getConnection();
ObjectName queueObjName = getObjNameforQueue(myQueue);
MBeanInfo mbeanInfo = connection.getMBeanInfo(objName);
MBeanOperationInfo[] ops = mbeanInfo.getOperations();
for(MBeanOperationInfo op: ops) {
    System.out.println("Operation Name: "+op.getName());
}
```

Please let me know how I can delete individual messages from the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. I wrote a message reciever for the queue with messageId as the selector

```
QueueReceiver receiver = ((QueueSession) session).createReceiver(queue, "JMSMessageID='"+messageId+"'");

for(;;) {

    Message message = receiver.receive();
    if(messageId.equals(message.getJMSMessageID())) {
        result = MSG_DEL_SUCCESS.replace("${msgId}", messageId);
        break;
    }
}
```